# List view of external content type with group by

Tags: list-view, external-content-type, web-part-page

I've got a list that displays data from an external content type.
The view uses group by on a single column and I want it to be rendered collapsed.

This view works just fine. And if I create a web part page and add the view to it everything works. But as soon as I add another web part to the page my view no longer works.
When the page is done loading and I try to expand one group it displays all items under that group and not just the items belonging to the group. And then I expand another group and again it renders all the items under that group same as it did the first group I expanded.

```
-Group1
    -Item1
-Group2
    -Item2
```

^This is what I want it to look like after both groups have been expanded but instead I get this:

```
-Group1
    -Item1
    -Item2
-Group2
    -Item1
    -Item2
```

If I select to render the view expanded when the page loads it works fine. But since there are a lot of items in each group and this being only one of many web parts on the page I don't want to render it expanded.

Has anyone had similar experience or have any idea how I can get this to work?